# list<T>::iterator is not working right

Tags: c++, list, typename

I am creating a template class in C++, and am using `std::list` in it. For some reason, my compiler doesn't like how I'm trying to declare and construct an iterator for the list.

In my HashTable.h file I have:

```
template <typename T> class HashTable {
    bool find(T thing) {
        // some code
        list<T>::iterator iter;
        for (iter = table[index].begin(); iter != table[index].end(); ++iter) {
            // some more code
        }
    }

}
```

And it gives me `HashTable.h:77: error: expected ';' before "iter"` as an error message.

What's the proper syntax for the iterator?

Or is that right, and I need to create an iterator class for each of the classes I intend to use in my HashTable template? If so, that would suck...

Comment: Add a `typename`. There's duplicates of this out there somewhere. [This might be a good read](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Comment: You are missing a bracket after the for loop.

Comment: @Cole - That's true, though in my full code it is present. Good eye!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `typename` to tell the compiler that `list<T>::iterator` is indeed a type in this context.

```
typename list<T>::iterator iter;
```

The reasons are fairly obscure; see the C++ FAQ for more details: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.18.

Comment: I remember the first time I stumbled upon that and, as the FAQ mentioned, it did in fact hurt my head.

Comment: Even my TAs were surprised by that one. Apparently it wasn't mentioned in class.